# VPC public subnet internet access with ELB hooked up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I am attempting to set up a web server (nginx) that needs access to the internet while also being hooked up to an ELB but I am having trouble getting this solution working.

**Details:**

- 3 public subnets

  - a
  - b
  - c
- 3 private subnets

  - a
  - b
  - c
- 1 ELB

  - This has the three public subnets included in its default pool
- 1 NAT instance in public subnet

The various guides I have found useful for getting the public subnets hooked up to the ELB by pointing the subnets to the IGW.  These set ups do not take in to consideration the need for internet access.

When I change the route table for the single NIC from the IGW to the nat instance I get internet access but I lose the ability to connect to the ELB and visa versa, when I update the route table to use the IGW I lose the ability to connect to the internet.

I can allocate an EIP and give it access that way but was hoping to avoid exposing this server the internet via a public address if possible.

What I am thinking is that I can either 1) add a second NIC to the web servers that need internet access so they have a leg out via a NAT instance and also have a leg in the public subnet to connect to the load balancer or 2) I can use the nat instance as the gateway for my network.

Has anybody set something similar to this up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a point, here.

It a machine has a public IP, it goes in a public subnet and uses the IGW as its default route.

If it doesn't have a public IP, it goes in a private subnet and uses a NAT instance as its default route.

That's it.  End of story.

If you have web servers without public addresses, behind an ELB... then the ELB itself goes in the *public* subnet, but the instances go in the *private* subnet.

The subnets where an ELB is provisioned have nothing to do with the subnets where the instances it is balancing are provisioned.

It's counterintuitive, but true nonetheless.

VPC isn't a LAN, so cross-subnet traffic does not "go through a router" in the same sense it would on a LAN, so there's no inefficiency with this approach.

Comment: Thanks again for clearing this up, for some reason I had the notion that subnet locations mattered.  I am new to ELB so was having a hard time thinking about it.

Comment: @jmreicha it's logical enough that machines with heavy traffic among them would belong on the same subnet, and I made the same assumption when I first got started, doing things the opposite way, putting the externally-visible ELB on the private subnet on the assumption that the auto-assigned public IPs on the ELB itself were on a secret 2nd NIC of the ELB with access to the Internet.  They aren't, and this config also won't work, but troubleshooting led me to an understanding of how to "think networking" the VPC way.

Comment: Another VPC answer of mine that you might find useful is [this one on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21924252/1695906), and certainly more interesting than that answer itself is the linked AWS video about the internals of how VPC networking works.  Suddenly, it makes sense why same subnet vs different subnet is not a factor.  VPC is the product of some rather brilliant engineering, from my perspective as a user of the platform.